# How can I loop through my form fields and add them to the rules/messages objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a for-loop that will add elements to my `validate` method.

I want to loop through each input element that starts with `user_input` and add it to my `rules` and `messages` object.

**It should add the following elements in my object:**

`user_number_X {
   checkLotteryNumber: true,
   required: true
}`

This is what I'm currently getting: 
[image]

But it should looks like:

`user_number_1: {
               checkLotteryNumber: true,
               required: true
           },
           user_number_2: {
              checkLotteryNumber: true,
               required: true
           },
           user_number_3: {
               checkLotteryNumber: true,
               required: true
           },`

**Here is my index.html**

```
<form class="user-input">
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_1">1st number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_1" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_1" type="number" maxlength="2" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_2">2nd number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_2" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_2" type="number" maxlength="2" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_3">3rd number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_3" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_3" type="number" maxlength="2" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_4">4th number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_4" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_4" type="number" maxlength="2" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_5">5th number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_5" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_5" type="number" maxlength="2" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user_number_6">6th number</label>
                    <input id="user_number_6" class="lottery-number" name="user_number_6" type="number" maxlength="2"required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-draw">Number of draws</label>
                    <input id="user-draw" class="draw-number" name="draw_number" type="number" required>
                    <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit-button">
                    <button id="button-send_results" class="submit" type="submit">Let's win!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**My js file:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkLotteryNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value > 0 && value <= 52;
}, 'Please, write numbers from 1 to 52 only');

$.validator.addMethod("checkDrawsNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value < 100000;
}, 'You can play not more than 99.999 draws');

var rules = {
    draw_number: {
        checkDrawsNumber: true,
        required: true
    }
}

var numberCheck = function() {
    $("input[id^='user_number']").each(function() {
        rules[$(this.id)] = {
            checkLotteryNumber: true,
            required: true
        };
    });
}
console.log(rules);
numberCheck();   

var messages = {
    draw_number: {
        checkDrawsNumber: 'You can play not more than 99.999 draws',
        required: 'This field is required'
    }
};

var drawsCheck = function() {
    $("input[id^='user_number']").each(function() {
        messages[$(this.id)] = {
            checkLotteryNumber: 'Please, write numbers from 1 to 52 only',
            required: 'This field is required'
        };
    });
}
console.log(messages);
drawsCheck() 

$('form.user-input').validate({
    rules: rules,

    messages: messages,
.....
```

Comment: what exactly the issue? do you have any errors? what happening now when you run this code?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: `rules[$(this.id)] = {...}` should be `rules[$(this).attr('id')] = {...}` or `rules[this.id] = {...}`